# How to arrange the mysqli result set in a multidiamentional array format?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find a way to structure my mysqli_result in a multi-dimentional array. What I mean by that is I have sql queries that will get result from multiple tables.

eg:

```php
$res = $mysqli->query(
    "SELECT a.*,
        b.a as `b.a`,
        b.b as `b.b`
        ...
    FROM table_a a, 
        LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    WHERE a.x = 'foo' AND a.y = 'bar'"
)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

The result I get from this is like

```
[
    [
        ...,
        b.a => 'foofoo',
        b.b => 'foobar'
    ],
    [
        ...,
        b.a => `barfoo`
        b.b => `barbar`
    ],
    ....
]
```

what I am trying to achive is to get the result like

```
[
    [
        ...,
        b => [
            a => foofoo',
            b => 'foobar'
        ]
    ],
    [
        ...,
        b => [
            a => barfoo',
            b => 'barbar'
        ]
    ],
    ....
]
```

I have tried doing

```php
$res = $mysqli->query(
    "SELECT a.*,
        b.a as `b[a]`,
        b.b as `b[b]`
        ...
    FROM table_a a, 
        LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    WHERE a.x = 'foo' AND a.y = 'bar'"
)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

/* and */

$res = $mysqli->query(
    "SELECT a.*,
        b.a as `b['a']`,
        b.b as `b['b']`
        ...
    FROM table_a a, 
        LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    WHERE a.x = 'foo' AND a.y = 'bar'"
)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

but the result is a ditto

```
[
    [
        ...,
        b[a] => 'foofoo',
        b[b] => 'foobar'
    ],
    [
        ...,
        b[a] => `barfoo`
        b[b] => `barbar`
    ],
    ....
]

/* and *

[
    [
        ...,
        b['a'] => 'foofoo',
        b['b'] => 'foobar'
    ],
    [
        ...,
        b['a'] => `barfoo`
        b['b'] => `barbar`
    ],
    ....
]
```

I have been inspired by php automatically converting form inputs named like array to actual array and hoped so; with no luck.

Is there a way to do this automatically without looping through all the result?

Comment: Without looping no possible.
You can use, PHP script for rearranging results to arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: _“Is there a way to do this automatically without looping through all the result?”_ - no.

Comment: MySQL doesn't understand PHP's arrays, so it cannot arrange data for you like that. You will have to reformat the result yourself.

Comment: @El_Vanja MySQL and mysqli are different right? I thought mysqli is PHP's

Comment: MySQL is the name of the DBMS. `mysql` and `mysqli` are two different PHP extensions allowing you to communicate with that kind of database.

Comment: You could probably achieve something close to this with PDO but definitely not with mysqli.

Comment: Oh I see. Its fine then. Thanks everybody